# In $\int a x\,dx$, is $a$ a constant, even though it can take different values?

Tags: calculus, terminology

Suppose I have the integral
$$\int a x\,dx$$
Now obviously $x$ is the variable here, but is it right to say $a$ is a constant?

Is it right to say we can use a letter to signify a constant, and if so, how is it that $a$ can be a constant if it can take different values, as a constant is defined as only taking one value?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341077/what-is-a-constant)

Comment: It is constant with respect to $x$. That is, we can change the value of $x$ without changing the value of $a$. This is not true for example of $f(x) = x^2$ . That is not constant with respect to $x$. But it is constant with respect to a new variable $y$ . So we could have $\int f(x) y\,dy$, and $f(x)$ would take the role of  $a$  here (with $y$ having taken the role of $x$) .